# How can i save disk space in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, space, sharding, disk

I have a three nodes cluster each of 114 GB disk capacity. I am pushing syslog events from around 190 devices to this server. The events flow at a rate of 100k withing 15 mins. The index has 5 shards and uses best_compression method. Inspite of this the disk gets filled up soon so i was forced to remove the replica for this index.  The index size is 170 GB and each shard is of size 34.1 GB. Now if i get additional disk space and i try to re index this data to a new index with 3 shards and replica will it save disk space ?

Comment: Actually you want to increase the number of shards so you get an even distribution across the disks, hopefully. Think of it as chapters in a book, the total size will be the same but you can split it into as many chunks as you want. Also how about purging the index on an interval (maybe day or week), since they are just logs an I assume not of much use being stored long term.

Comment: Actually the retention period is 1 year. How big a shard can be. Tomorrow if i am scaling the cluster horizontally for example if i add two more data nodes how many shard can i keep ? How to increase shards just like changing replica ? Do i need to re index to a new one or can i do it within the same index ?

Comment: See here for a detailed analysis from elastic https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-many-shards-should-i-have-in-my-elasticsearch-cluster